# Upgrade angular-cli from version 1.7.4 to latest 9 in Angular 8 project

Tags: angular, angular-cli

After upgrading the cli using the commands below:

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest

ng update @angular/cli --from=1.7.4 
--migrate-only --allow-dirty (to convert the angular-cli.json to angular.json)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR in ./app/assets/less/bootstrap/input-groups.less (./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":true,"minimize":false}!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"sourceMap":true,"modifyVars":{"root":"/"~@angular/../../"","styles":"/"~@angular/../../app/assets/less
/""}}!./app/assets/less/bootstrap/input-groups.less)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js)
```

any idea?

Comment: Can you show your config.js file please

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try upgrading your angular/core ?

```
ng update @angular/core
```

Comment: its happening also with cli version 8. the same as the project...